# How to deal with JSON pagination?

Tags: json

I want to make this call to an API:

```
curl -X GET --header 'Accept: application/json' 'https://unstats.un.org/sdgapi/v1/sdg/Indicator/Data?indicator=2.2.1&indicator=2.2.2&indicator=3.1.2&indicator=3.2.1&indicator=3.2.2&indicator=3.b.1&indicator=4.2.1&indicator=5.2.1&indicator=5.2.2&indicator=5.3.1&indicator=6.1.1&indicator=6.2.1&indicator=8.7.1&indicator=16.2.1&indicator=16.2.3&indicator=16.9.1&indicator=1.1.1&indicator=1.2.1&indicator=1.2.2&indicator=1.3.1&indicator=3.1.1&indicator=3.3.1&indicator=3.7.2&indicator=3.8.1&indicator=3.9.1&indicator=4.1.1&indicator=4.1.2&indicator=4.2.2&indicator=4.a.1&indicator=7.1.2&indicator=10.3.1&indicator=13.1.1&indicator=16.1.1&indicator=16.1.2&indicator=17.8.1&indicator=17.19.2&indicator=1.b.1&areaCode=051&areaCode=268'
```

where the JSON response is:

```
object {7}
size: 25
totalElements: 5137
totalPages: 206
pageNumber: 1
attributes[4]
dimensions[12]
data[25]
```

You can see it's only page 1 out of 206.
I intended to use this as data source for a PowerBI dashboard... How can I access the data of the other 205 pages? Is there a way to skip pagination?

Comment: *"Is there a way to skip pagination?"* - That depends on the API.  Does the API you're accessing provide any documentation on how to use it?  Does that documentation discuss pagination at all?

Comment: I suspect it is [this endpoint](https://unstats.un.org/sdgs/UNSDGAPIV5/swagger/index.html#operations-Indicator-get_v1_sdg_Indicator_Data), which defines a `page` parameter. Append `&page=2` to your URL for the second page. Maaaaybe you can skip pagination by specifying a very large `pageSize` parameter, but the API might have limits there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Amadan suggested, **pageSize=XXX** and **page=X** are the way to go.